# Помогите добавить максимум и минимум в регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$r1 =  '/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9_-]*$/i';
$r2=  '/^[a-z0-9]*$/i';
```

На обеих: минимум 1 максимум 10.

Comment: Максимум-минимум чего?

Comment: Регулярки - сущий ад

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#.D0.9A.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.28.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.B9.29

Comment: Минимум и максимум символов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Со второй регуляркой проблем возникнуть не должно, используем *ограничивающий квантификатор* (`{мин,макс}`), как обычно:

```
$r2 = '/^[a-z0-9]{1,10}$/i';
                 ^^^^^^
```

Со второй сложнее, так как в ней содержится последовательность квантифицированных шаблонов. В ней нужно использовать блок предварительного просмотра назад, например положительный `(?=.{1,10}$)`, который требует наличия строго от 1 до 10 любых символов, отличных от знаков перехода на новую строку:

```
$r1 = '/^(?=.{1,10}$)[a-z]+[a-z0-9_-]*$/i';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

или отрицательный `(?!.{11})`, который вернет false, если после начала строки есть 11 любых символов:

```
$r1 =  '/^(?!.{11})[a-z]+[a-z0-9_-]*$/i';
          ^^^^^^^^^
```

**См. пример работы [регулярного выражения №1](https://regex101.com/r/uuyiqs/1) и [регулярного выражения №2](https://regex101.com/r/uuyiqs/2).**

Comment: который требует наличия строго от 1 до 10 любых символов,  - а мне нужно не любых а тех которые указаны в регулярке. В итоге для второй регулярки нету требуемое решение ?

Comment: Вы не поняли, это и есть решение. Эта регулярка будет работать, так как после проверки длины, движок приступит к проверке строки на соответствие основному шаблону. Конечно, можно изменить блок просмотра вперед след. образом:  `$r1 = '/^(?=[a-z0-9_-]{1,10}$)[a-z]+[a-z0-9_-]*$/i';`, чтобы он проверял только  наличие разрешенных символов. Это будет работать так же.

Comment: Большое спасибо